# Building Inferred Virtuoso Model in Jena

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology, virtuoso, inference

I have a set of ontologies and RDF data stored in a Virtuoso Open Source 07.20.3217 version. Namely, these are the ontologies that I have stored:

- BOT (http://w3id.org/bot)
- SEAS Feature of Interest (https://w3id.org/seas/FeatureOfInterestOntology)
- SAREF (http://w3id.org/saref)
- M3-LITE (http://purl.org/iot/vocab/m3-lite#)

I want to load all these ontologies and RDF data into a model, apply a reasoner to infer new data, and apply a SPARQL over such new model with inferences. To do the first part, I am using the following code (which can be found in many tutorials).

```
    //Connect to Virtuoso and retrieve data stored in "GRAPH_NAME"
    Model model = VirtModel.openDatabaseModel(GRAPH_NAME, URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    //Create an ontology model based on the loaded data
    OntModel mod1 = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM, model);

    //Create an OWL reasoner
    Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
    reasoner = reasoner.bindSchema(mod1);

    //Apply the reasoner to the model
    InfModel inf = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, mod1);

(...)
```

In fact I have tried many variants of this code. However, I always get the same error when executing the `bindSchema()` function:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoException:
 SQ074: Line 1: SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 1: syntax error at '_' before ':'
```

Anyone dealing with the same problems?

Comment: First thoughts, please [confirm you're using the latest JDBC Driver and Jena Provider](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtJenaProvider). Similarly, what version of [Jena](http://jena.apache.org/) are you using? You might also consider updating to the [latest `/develop/7` Virtuoso](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commits/develop/7). Then, consider raising (what appears to be) a Virtuoso-specific question to Virtuoso-specific [Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com) or [github project issue](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/)...

Comment: 1) a pretty old Jena version is used here, note the latest is `3.10.0` 2) when you do it like this and want to do reasoning, you can load the whole data directly into Jena. I don't see any benefit of having the data in Virtuoso when reasoning is done in-memory anyways

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The only reason why I am using these old versions is because it is the only examples I found on the Internet. As for the 2), I am not sure if I get what you mean. I want to have a repository where changes can be made in data. So, everytime I need to make a SPARQL query, I need to load the data (which could be previously updated) into a Model, make the inferences in-memory, and return the result. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @AKSW - How can you tell what version of Jena is in use? I can see nothing here that gives any hint of it... As to Virtuoso's benefits -- TDB has a fairly limited feature set; Jena as framework plus Virtuoso as persistent store brings lots of benefits from Virtuoso's other features.

Comment: @User23 - I would expect that most of the "examples [you] found on the Internet" will work with recent if not current versions of the software on which they're based. If not, perhaps you should adjust your search terms, or ask questions on sites which are focused on Jena, Virtuoso, or whatever other tools you've decided to use.

Comment: @TallTed the error message shows `com.hp.hpl.jena` as package which was only in Jena 2.x and before - with Jena 3.x it was changed to `org.apache.jena`